# Creating a global function that withholds for loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, global-variables

How do I create a for loop that can be used in other functions?

How do I create a global variable with for loops?

```js
arrayNr1 = [4,8,13,2]
    arrayNr2 = [1,2,3,13]
    function globalLoop(array1, array2) {
      for(var i=0; i<array1.length; i++) {
        for(var j=0; j<array2.length; j++){
          if(array1[i] == array2[j]) {
            return array2[j]
          }
        }
       }
    }
    console.log(globalLoop(arrayNr1,arrayNr2)); //-> 13
```

Why is it only returning 13 instead of 13 and 2?

Comment: You are returning hence only `13`

Comment: You are using `return` before checking for element `2`

Answer (score 2):

The *first time* the `if` statement is true, the function will *return*.

The loop won't keep going and return more things.

A function can only return a single thing, and a return statement will stop the function from running further.

---

If you want to find *every* match, then you need to store matches somewhere (such as another array) and return *after the loops have finished*.

Answer (score 0):

You exit the function at the first find.

```
return array2[j]
```

You could collect the values with an array.

```js
function globalLoop(array1, array2) {
    var result = [], i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < array2.length; j++){
            if (array1[i] == array2[j]) {
                result.push(array1[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

var arrayNr1 = [4, 8, 13, 2],
    arrayNr2 = [1, 2, 3, 13];

console.log(globalLoop(arrayNr1,arrayNr2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check it:

```
arrayNr1 = [4,8,13,2];
arrayNr2 = [1,2,3,13];
arrayFinal = [];
function globalLoop(array1, array2) {
  for(var i=0; i<array1.length; i++) {
    for(var j=0; j<array2.length; j++){
      if(array1[i] == array2[j]) {
        arrayFinal.push(array2[j])
      }
    }
   }
}
globalLoop(arrayNr1,arrayNr2);
console.log(arrayFinal);
```

Comment: Please explain what and why have you changed. Also, check other answers if you are not repeating something

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over arrayNr1 first and the first match in both arrays is (13, 13). The return statement stops the loop on the first match, it never gets to the second.

The following snippet collects all matches and returns an array.

```js
arrayNr1 = [4,8,13,2]
    arrayNr2 = [1,2,3,13]
    function globalLoop(array1, array2) {
      var equal_elements = [];
      for(var i=0; i<array1.length; i++) {
        for(var j=0; j<array2.length; j++){
          if(array1[i] == array2[j]) {
            // collect matches
            equal_elements.push(array2[j]);
          }
        }
       }
       return equal_elements;
    }
    console.log(globalLoop(arrayNr1,arrayNr2));
```